# How to view the list of tables along with columns and their data types in a particular schema?

Tags: postgresql

In Postgres, I need the information of all the tables along with the columns present in the table with their data type in a particular schema.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html or https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalogs.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html), do a `\d your_schema.*`

`psql` has an additional feature: when you do `\set ECHO_HIDDEN on` beforehand, you'll receive the queries used for producing the output.  You can save these queries and reuse them in any client you prefer.

These queries do a bit more than what you strictly need, so you can safely omit some of them.  This exercise is left to the reader ;)